# navigation controller can't back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

UINavigationController pushes from controllerA to controllerB,
 **but the navigation bar still show controllerA's** . (custom content is controllerB,the navigation bar is controllerB's is right result)

Here is few lines from my method

```
MKMCComboListTVC *controllerVC = [[MKMCComboListTVC alloc] init]; 
[self.navigationController showViewController:controllerVC sender:nil];
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 MYAddShopTVC *controllerVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MYAddShopTVC"];
 controllerVC.nameList = transNameList;
 [self.navigationController showViewController:controllerVC sender:nil];
```

then when I click back button, controller is not poped back. It shows ViewController from controllerB to controllerC, custom content is in the controllerC, the navigation bar is controllerA's. In short it can push next controller ,but can't back.  so navigation bar doesn't match custom content.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show some code...

Comment: this question occur  not sure  which controller,and  it  happen again  little, 
 
 show next controller i used this two methods
 
 MKMCComboListTVC *controllerVC = [[MKMCComboListTVC alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController showViewController:controllerVC sender:nil];
 
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 MYAddShopTVC *controllerVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MYAddShopTVC"];
 controllerVC.nameList = transNameList;
 [self.navigationController showViewController:controllerVC  sender:nil];

Comment: @jinglu we can't help you when you post unreadable code in comments. The code you posted looks good.

Comment: try `self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerVC animated: YES];`